# Android GridView not displaying records in empty search box

Tags: android, gridview

This is what my app does, user can search via searchbox. When he types something and matches, it filters the gridview. But when he tries to delete, no records display.
I'm stuck at displaying whole records when emptying search box.

this is what I've tried:

**MainActivity.class:**

```
  etSearch.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {

        @Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence cs, int arg1, int arg2, int arg3) {
                adapter.getFilter().filter(cs.toString());


        }

        @Override
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence arg0, int arg1, int arg2, int arg3) {

        }

        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable cs) {

        }
    });
```

CustomAdapter.class:

```
  @Override
public Filter getFilter() {
    if (starsFilter == null)
        starsFilter = new StarsFilter();
    return starsFilter;
}

private class StarsFilter extends Filter {

    @Override
    protected FilterResults performFiltering(CharSequence constraint) {
        // Create a FilterResults object
        FilterResults results = new FilterResults();

        constraint = constraint.toString().toLowerCase();

        if (constraint != null && constraint.toString().length() > 0) {
            ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> filteredStars = new ArrayList<>();
            for(HashMap<String, String> item : data){
                if(item.toString().toLowerCase().contains(constraint)){
                    filteredStars.add(item);
                }
            }
            results.values = filteredStars;
            results.count = filteredStars.size();
        } else {
            synchronized(this) {
                results.values = data;
                results.count = data.size();
            }
        }

        // Return our FilterResults object
        return results;
    }

    @Override
    protected void publishResults(CharSequence constraint, FilterResults results) {
        data.clear();

        if (constraint.length() == 0) {
            notifyDataSetInvalidated();
        } else {
            for (HashMap<String, String> result : (ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>) results.values) {
                data.add(result);
            }
            notifyDataSetChanged();
        }

    }


}
```

Any ideas? I'd appreciate your help. Thanks in advance!

Comment: What is the problem? It's not clear from the question.

Comment: What you really trying yo do, where you are blocking

Comment: @Lingviston I've updated my post

Comment: @Sree pls. see my updated post.

Answer (score 0):

First of all do not use single `ArrayList` called `data` to store initial results and filtered result. Notice that in publishresults you at the first clear your `data` so once user used search - original data partly/completly lost.

So have 2 `ArrayList`s in your adapter called `originalData` and `filteredData` for example. `originalData` must not change during filtering. Initially `filteredData` must be a copy of `originalData` and your adapter must always use `filteredData` as source dataset.

In perform filtering you must modify/clear/fill `filteredData`. If `constraint` is empty string you have to just copy all `originalData` content into `filteredData`.

Then in `publishResults` change your check from `constraint.length() == 0` to `results.count == 0`.

Comment: http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/2.0_r1/android/widget/ArrayAdapter.java Default ArrayAdapter implementation is very similar. The main point is to ahve 2 datasets. Maybe this example is too heavy but I think with my explanation you can handle your problem.